# What is it called to replace a word(s) in a well known idiom/quotes and turn it into a true statement for humor?

Tags: idioms, puns

Today I was watching a live streamer on Twitch (a veteran gamer in 'Day Z', an open world, zombie survival/shooter video game) and there was a scenario in the game where he came across 2 other players trying to defeat each other until the streamer intervened by calling them over to a rock and showed them how to make a "stone spear head" from the rock (to make things more interesting).

Moments later someone in the streamers live chat feed said, "You just blew 2 minds with 1 stone".

Is this simply a turn-of-phrase pun or an idiomatic pun?
Or is there another title for this?

Comment: That statement contains a mixed metaphor (combining "to blow one's mind" with "killed two birds with one stone"). However, you seem to be asking about the fact that a word in the idiom ("stone") applies literally to the situation.

Comment: The newness of the pun is what makes it original, not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the phrase, it seems to be a combination of "to blow one's mind" and "to kill two birds with one stone", so the phrase itself isn't quite an idiom by itself; therefore this is simply a turn-of-phrase pun, if only perhaps inspired by the two aforementioned idioms.